Magento 2 - Add Simple Products to Configurable Product, only virtual products appear
I have created a configurable product and it is always mandatory to create a product, Magento creates them as a virtual product, and then the option to add products manually appears, when I click on the option only virtual type products appear. I want to add simple products, is there a way so that when I click on the option simple products appear?



==============
Edit:
When I add weight the products are saved as a Simple Product, but what I need is to add existing Simple Products, because when I click on "Select -> Choose a different product" only the Virtual Products are shown, as seen below:




As you can see, the problem is that when I want to add a different product, only the existing Virtual Products appear, in this case Buzo Virtual. Is there a way to get the Simple Products in that list?

If you add weight at the time of product generation then Magneto generates a simple product
I saw the screenshot that you have provided, there is no weight available That is why it creates a virtual product.

Please read this. "Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat."

@Sanjay Jethva please check edit

When you create your configurable product, input a value in the Weight attribute field.

Please check edit

When you create your configurable product, Magento asks you to select the "configurable" attributes (Step 1).
These attributes should be present in the simple product you want to add. If the product is missing one of the attributes selected previously, it won't appear.
